# Nuxt Vue `this.$axios` is `undefined` even though I set a `nuxt.config.js` file in the root directory

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

`this.$axios` is `undefined`. As I said in the title I set `nuxt.config.js`. This is what the error looks like.

[image]

This is the HomeView.vue page code where the error is occurring (I removed some methods as they aren't relevant) BTW, notice the line `console.log(this.$axios);` because this is what printed `undefined` in the web console:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button
      color="primary"
      class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
      large
      :disabled="buttonDisabled"
      @click="performAction()"
    >
      <span v-if="isMetaMaskInstalled()">Login with Metamask</span>
      <span v-if="!isMetaMaskInstalled()">{{ buttonInstallText }}</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <span></span>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
    @click="register()"
  >
    Block level button
  </button>
</template>

<script>
import Web3 from "web3";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      buttonDisabled: false,
      buttonInstallText: "Click here to install Metamask",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    basicLog() {
      console.log("it worked");
    },
    testAxiosCall() {
      console.log("test call worked");
    },
    async register() {
      console.log(this.$axios);
      const result = await this.$axios.post("/register", {
        wallet: "0x00fffff",
      });
      return result;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I already installed axios with `yarn add @nuxtjs/axios` and set up my nuxt config file:

```js
export default {
  modules: ["@nuxtjs/axios"],
  axios: {
    baseURL: "http://localhost:30005",
  },
};
```

Btw, the function localhost:30005/register works perfectly in Postman when I add the parameter wallet: 0x00fffff.
[image]

Also here is the code for the register api call. It's in `backend/index.js`

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();

let port = "30005";

let db = new sqlite3.Database(path.resolve(__dirname, "bonus_content.db"));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
app.use(cors());

const registerUser = (request, response) => {
  const { wallet } = request.body;
  console.log(wallet);
  db.run(
    "INSERT INTO bonus_content (wallet) VALUES ($1)",
    [wallet],
    (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        response.status(500).json({ status: "fail", message: error });
      }
      response
        .status(201)
        .json({ status: "success", message: "Wallet added." });
    }
  );
};

app.post("/register", registerUser);

// allow javascript on a different domain (or port) to call this server's routes
// e.g. front-end running on localhost:8080 can call the server on localhost:41205

app.listen(port);
console.log("App is running on port " + port);
```

So the problem is centered around `this.$axios` being `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Btw, It's worth noting that I am going off of this tutorial here: https://duartefdias.medium.com/authenticating-users-to-your-web-app-using-metamask-and-nodejs-e920e45e358

Comment: If you are using `@nuxtjs/axios` NPM package than `this.$axios` will be automatically defined.

Comment: Yeah I used `yarn add @nuxtjs/axios` but it is still undefined.

Comment: Where is the error? On `app.post` or `this.$axios.post`?

Comment: It's on the line `const result = await this.$axios.post("/register", {` and it's because `this.$axios` is undefined

Comment: What if you try `@click="register"`?

Comment: Same thing, it's undefined and fails

Comment: Try a `get` into a `mounted` hook just for testing purposes.

Comment: Also, what is undefined the `console.log` or the payload itself? Do you have something in the network tab?

Comment: It's definitely the payload itself that's undefined. My network tab doesn't seem to have anything abnormal. I could send you the screenshot if you think it will help. Also, how do I try a `get` into a `mounted` hook? I'm not familiar with that process.

Comment: Try something like this `async mounted() { const res = await this.$axios.$get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'); console.log('res', res) }` and check if you see it in the network tab.

Comment: Since the questioner says `this.$axios` returns `undefined` , trying a `get` request doesn't seem to be helpful tho.  Not sure this is the recommended way to go. @kissu

Comment: @bar5um agreed, but I don't see how we could troubleshot it further without a [repro] or anything showing us what may be the issue here. The usage of `axios` is pretty straightforward in Nuxt usually.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for mentioning my article, glad you found it useful.

First, you need to make sure you have axios installed as mentioned here:
https://axios.nuxtjs.org/setup

My nuxt.config.js axios setup looks like this:

```
export default {
  axios: {
    browserBaseURL: process.env.API_URL
  }
}
```

The process.env.API_URL is an environment variable I created, but you can simply hardcode a string such as "http://localhost:3000"

Then I just call this.$axios from anywhere in the code. Example of a basic .vue page:

```html
<template>
    <button @click="getData()">
        My Button
    </button>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        components: {},
        data () {
            return {
              items: []
            }
        },

        methods: {
            getData() {
                this.$axios.get('/items')
                .then(response => {
                    this.items = response.data
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If I were you I would start by building a dummy backend endpoint which simply returns a string and getting that to work with Vue prior to moving into building the blockchain wallet register/login endpoints.